# Is not a valid integer value

Tags: c++builder, c++

Дан целочисленный массив  А[10]. Минимальный элемент этого массива заменить целой частью среднего арифметического всех элементов массива, остальные члены оставить без изменения.

```
const int N=10;
int min,i,summ,A[10];
float sr;
for (i=0;i<=N-1;i++)
  A[i+1]=StrToInt(StringGrid1->Cells[i][0]);
{
  min=A[1];
  summ=A[1];
}
for (i=2; i<=N;i++)
{
  summ=summ+A[i];
  if(min>A[i])
    min=A[i];
}
sr=summ/N;
summ-=(int)sr;
A[i+1]=StrToInt(StringGrid1->Cells[i][0]);
for (i=1; i<=N;i++)
  StringGrid1->Cells[i][0]=IntToStr(summ);
```

Не могу понять, в чём дело. Ошибка выдаётся уже в работающей программе, при нажатии на кнопку выполнения действия.

Comment: Начнем с того, что у Вас массивы неверно используются - индексация вообще то начинается с 0, а не с 1, как в Вашем коде.

Comment: Для начала, в какой строке выдаётся ошибка? Какие значения у переменных, упомянутых в этой строке? Это правильные значения, или нет?